# What is the keyboard layout environment variable?

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout, environment-variables

I want a script to run when I press a keyboard shortcut, but only if I’m using a specific keyboard layout (I have 4 installed).
I figured the easiest way to do this was with the keyboard layout environment variable (provided there is one), but I couldn’t find anything of the sort.

Any help is welcome.  I’m open to other ideas, I just thought this would be easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there is no environment variable with that info.

If you are on standard Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the keyboard layout in use is the first one in the list generated by this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources
```

However, I just found out that that does not work as expected on Ubuntu 20.10. Maybe related to [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1258).

Comment: I get `@a(ss) []` back when I run this.  I also need it in a variable, so I can use it in a script.  I’m running Zorin OS 15.3, I don’t know what version of Ubuntu it’s based in.

Comment: @RowanAckerman: Zorin is off topic at Ask Ubuntu. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: OK.  From past experience, their terminals are almost identical, so what works for Ubuntu, works for Zorin.  Evidently this is not always the case.  I’ll ask this on unix/linux.  thanks.